# Alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let series $\displaystyle \sum _{n=n_0}^{+\infty}(-1)^na_n$ satisfy Leibniz convergence criterion. Let $\displaystyle r_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}(-1)^ka_k$. Prove that $r_n$ has the same sign as its first term and $|r_n|<a_{n+1}$.

Well, so far I used this fact several times but never consider proving it. In my opinion proofs of simple facts are not so obvious. I don't know how to precise show it.

Comment: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets) should give you some ideas.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the fact that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ is convergent.

Keep in mind that that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of nonnegative terms that decrease to zero.

Suppose $n$ is even, say $n=2m$. Then
$$\eqalign{
0&\ge (\underbrace{-a_{2m+1}+ a_{2m+2}}_{\le 0})+(\underbrace{-a_{2m+3}+ a_{2m+4}}_{\le0})+\cdots\cr 
&=\sum_{k=2m+1}^\infty (-1)^k a_k  \cr
&=-a_{2m+1}+(\underbrace{a_{2m+2} -a_{2m+3}}_{\ge0}) +(\underbrace{a_{2m+4} -a_{2m+5}}_{\ge 0})+\cdots\cr
&\ge -a_{2m+1}\cr
&=-a_{n+1}.
}
$$

So $$\tag{1}0\ge r_n\ge -a_{n+1},\quad\text{for }\ n\ \text{even}.$$

For $n$ odd, one can show similarly that 
$$\tag{2}0\le r_n\le a_{n+1},\quad\text{for }\ n\ \text{odd}.$$

Inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ show that $|r_n|\le a_{n+1}$ and that $r_n$ has the same sign as $(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to use some properties and that can be found  on the wikipedia. Notice that
$r_n = L - S_n $ where $L = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}a_n $ and $ S_n \sum_{n=0}^{k} 
(-1)^{n}a_n $. Then
$$ |r_n| = | L - S_n| \le a_n, $$
and the firt term of $r_n$ is $\ge 0 $ if $n$ is odd, but if $n$ is even
$$ r_n = L - S_n \ge 0 .$$
Analagously, if $n$ is even
$$ r_n = L - S_n \le 0 .$$